Question about Artin's Algebra Example 3.3.4 on vector space

Example 3.3.4 Let $F$ be the prime field $\mathbb{F_p}$. The space $F^2$ contains $p^2$ vectors, $p^2-1$ of which are nonzero. Because there are $p-1$ nonzero scalars, the subspace $W=\{cw\}$ spanned by a nonzero vector $w$ will contain $p-1$ nonzero vectors. Therefore $F^2$ contains $(p^2-1)/(p-1)=p+1$ proper subspaces.

My question is how to guarantee the $p^2-1$ $w$s are linearly independent.
(If this cannot be guaranteed, then there would be a $w_1$ and $w_2$ such that $cw_1=w_2$.)
Thank you all in advance!

They aren't...?

Why would they be ??

I think you're not quite understanding what's going on here.  Let's list off all of the non-zero vectors of $F^2$ in a column.  There are exactly $p^2-1$ of them.  List them in any order you like -- it won't matter.
Each vector is contained in exactly one proper subspace of $F^2$.  In a second column next to the first, let's write down the proper subspace that contains the corresponding non-zero vector.
Since each proper subspace contains exactly $p-1$ non-zero vectors, our second column lists each subspace exactly $p-1$ times -- once for each non-zero vector it contains.  There are exactly $p^2-1$ non-zero vectors, so both of the columns we just wrote down have exactly $p^2-1$ rows.  Therefore, there are exactly $\frac{p^2-1}{p-1}=p+1$ different subspaces listed in the second column.  Our second column contains all possible non-zero proper subspaces of $F^2$, so $F^2$ contains exactly $p+1$ non-zero proper subspaces.
Nowhere in this discussion do we need any set of vectors to be linearly independent.

Thank you! Now I understand!
